# How Current List Entry in Oracle Apex works?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an app with page. In a page there is an item that I use in query. So in Menu Entry I set Target = my page with item value (e.g. :P1_TYPE = 1). I have 3 menu entry that refers to one page but setting :P1_TYPE = 1 or 2 or 3. Everything works fine, but in side navigation menu active tab always first. I see "Current List Entry" in "List Entry" but don't understand how it works. I tried sql queries, pl/sql expressions that return :P1_TYPE = (1 | 2 | 3) but it doesn't work anyway.
[image: List Entry edit page]

Comment: What does "but in side navigation menu active tab always first" mean ?

Comment: [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/RvMVWav)
It means that the first tab expanded always. In every tab I refer to page 1 and page 2 and fill P1_TYPE by different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would use the "Expression > pl/sql" option with condition

```
:P1_TYPE = '1'
```

for the first menu entry (where you're setting P1_TYPE to value 1 in the url), for the other pages use 2 and 3

Here is how I tested it on my local env:

[image]

--UPDATED--

Note that if you have tabs pointing to a different pages then it might be needed to included the page number in the expression. For example in the source above the value for `P1_TYPE` might exist in cache and cause the condition to yield true when the user is on page 2. It is safer to do the following:

```
:P1_TYPE = 1 AND :APP_PAGE_ID = 1
```

Comment: Where I should write it? It’s my question

Comment: [Screen record](https://imgur.com/aG9lDGd). Doesn't work :(

Comment: In my answer there are quotes around the value, can you try that ? If that doesn't work then I'd suggest you create a reproducible case on apex.oracle.com (workspace SO_HELP, username/pwd SO_76946657/SO_76946657) and I'll have a look

Comment: You can check it, it doesn't work

Comment: Check updated answer. In your question you said "3 menu entry that refers to one page" but in your example app you have 2 pages. Also, whenever you ask/comment in forums please do not use the words "it doesn't work". That doesn't mean anything. Instead, explain what you are expecting to see and what you are actually seeing. Note - those quotes were not needed, that wasn't the issue sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I fixed VAL1 > tab 1 and VAL1 > tab 2 in that example. I assume that is what you meant. If it's not the please explain in detail what behaviour you're expecting.